# starting a web app to run python

Tags: python, django

I have a web app that I am working on right now, and have pretty much finish building it with Django. I have been looking online for ways to deploy it like Heroku and webfaction. These seem like good ideas, but I was wondering if anyone had any better ones, or any servers they prefer over those two. I don't need to have that many users, maybe 100 max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a bit too broad and it contains a couple of quirky/odd assumptions.

Django is an MVC framework allowing you to build sophisticated web applications. Often such applications rely on a DB (RDBMS, noSQL, etc)  to store their data.

In HW, a website is the server providing such applications. The DB can be decoupled and run elsewhere.

In SW, the web application is provided to the clients by a web server application (e.g. Apache) which interacts with Python which runs your Django app which interacts with the DB.

From your description I can say Apache+Django+Postgres+[cron or Celery] should be enough to deliver the kind of service you have in mind.

However, nowadays there are many more options available in terms of SW architecture.

I suggest to get the work done using a standard solution and take the project off the ground.

It will allow you to play with it and evaluate if it can match what you envision.

Later you can start considering factors like the load of requests the app must withstand. And maybe change approach completely.

Improve your skills in Python and Django and start developing a small app with the core functionalities.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks I will look into using these frameworks, but how does running the python scripts work. When a user creates an account on my website, how does that information get transferred to a script?

Comment: Look online for tutorials about web programming in general. Here are a few links for Django [one](http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-find-a-good-Django-tutorial-for-beginners), [two](https://youtu.be/zTNA0MtZwso), [three](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/) and [four](https://www.djangoproject.com/start/)

Comment: ok thanks as long as my idea is possible with this, ill do it. dont wanna waste my time

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend `Web2py`: http://www.web2py.com/. It is quite easy to work with, and is also quite powerful.

Web2py does not require a server to run on in order to broadcast publicly. Most any desktop computer running OS X, Windows, or Linux is capable of displaying your webpage.

The integrated scheduler seems easy enough to implement, considering variables returned by controllers are accessible through the scheduler as indicated here: 
http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#web2py-Scheduler.

On top of all that Web2py offers a "Database abstraction layer", which is basically a fancy way of saying that the SQL database code is generated for you. More information may be found here: 
http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#The-database-abstraction-layer